# TextMate's Dawn color theme for Emacs

Tags: emacs, themes, textmate

Does anybody know if there is a color theme like the TextMate Dawn theme, for Emacs ? I simply don't like the way the fonts look on my dark emacs theme and I am not sure if it's emacs's fault or just the theme.

Here's a comparison:

http://mixandgo.com/emacs_textmate.png

Thanks,
Cezar

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 8):

Um, why do you have a dark Emacs?

Do `M-x color-theme-select` (maybe you'll need to install `color-theme` first: do `sudo  apt-get install emacs-goodies-el` or see [Emacswiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki?ColorTheme)), and pick a light one. There are lots; many with "light" or "gray" in their name. (I like Greiner, Wheat, Snow, etc.)

Also, maybe you want to turn on/off anti-aliasing?

Comment: For some reason, this answer suggesting light color themes like [TextMate's Dawn theme](http://wiki.macromates.com/Themes/UserSubmittedThemes) that the OP wants is repeatedly downvoted, while the other answer recommending a dark theme exactly unlike what the OP wants is upvoted. :-| I will of course delete this answer if it's unhelpful, but I'd really like to know why it's thought so.

Answer (score 4):

After installing color-theme for Emacs:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme

You can download this theme which is similar to the TextMate color scheme:

http://blog.jdhuntington.com/2008/11/emacs-color-theme-blackboard.html